# How to apply for the 5 year Schengen visa under the updated Schengen Visa Code?

Tags: schengen-visas

According to the updates to the Schengen Visa Code with effect from February  2020, a person with a good travel history can ask for a 5 year visa.

I used to travel for business and tourism. How can I ask for a 5 year visa?

And how to book flights and hotels in this case? Should it covers the first entry only?

What about insurance policy?

Comment: Please edit the question and use a better title.

Comment: According to https://www.immihelp.com/schengen-visa-types/ you’ll need to justify why you need a long-term visa. It would be reasonable to assume that all other application /  documentary requirements such as travel insurance, flights/hotels etc would be the same as for any multiple entry visa.

Comment: Five year visas are not new.  The conditions for issuing them are being changed somewhat, in that there is an explicit general condition of having had a two-year visa in the preceding three year period.  Exceptions are possible, however.  Have you had such a visa?